# mysql query on node.js is giving me a object object result

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi

I have this query on node.js. This is my server side file:

```
    function doquery(select,from,where,value) {
     var con = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "localhost",
          database: "db545",
          user: "root",
          password: "mypass"
        });
        
     return con.query("SELECT " + select + " FROM " + from + " WHERE " + where + value);
    };
    
   io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
      socket.on('add user', (username) => {
        dispname = doquery('name','members','member_id','1');
```

but the variable dispname is resulting in [object object] but since this is server side Im not getting any errors so I cant debug it. What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: seems that everything is fine, it returns the result object (handler)

Comment: "so I cant debug it" << you could attach a debugger to your process. You use a locl debugger to debug a remote process by forwarding port 9229 from your server via SSH, sending SIGUSR1 to the process to enable debug mode (or enable it from the start by passing `--inspect` to `node`) and then connecting with the Chrome devtools' "node" button which will appear in the toolbar at that point - or VSCode's debugger. In VSCode you can even use the remote mode (bottom-left corner) to do the whole thing with a nice interface. This will allow you to debug code running on a server.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Also I think the issue is that you are getting a promise returned and you don't `await` it. (It's not clear because you didn't show which mysql package you are using exactly, there are multiple.)

Comment: but do what? `con.query` doesn't return the result... it has a callback to return the result, you are just doing it wrong, read the documentation... `con.query(your_query, function (error, results, fields) {...}`

Comment: could you please elaborate on that? Because I already know Im doing it wrong, the question is HOW.

Answer (score 2):

`[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object. If you want to properly debug the result, you could serialize it to JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dispname));
```

**Side note:**
By concatenating strings to your SQL query like that you're making the application vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. I strongly recommend you look into [prepared statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries) instead.

Comment: I cant log it into the console because its server side. Also, I tried JSON.stringify(dispname) but my app crashes. I get a 500 error.

Comment: Why can't you look at your _server's console_ then?

Comment: I did but Im getting nothing.